# Azure automation account - how to use custom service principal for login instead of run as account?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

In Azure automation account - how to use already existing service principal for login in powershell runbook instead of run as account ?

we dont get privilege to create service principal at our organisation .. 
so would like to use already existing service principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the command below.

```
$azureAplicationId ="<client-id>"
$azureTenantId= "<tenant-id>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<client-secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
```

[image]